# Distinguish between HttpClient request failure types

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-status-codes, dotnet-httpclient

I need to write code to handle the 2 distinct types of failures that can arise after issuing an HTTP request using an `HttpClient` object that comes with .Net Framework 4.5:

1. Connectivity failures, when the server can not be reached due to connection problems - e.g. no connection available, timeout expiration, incorrect network settings etc.
2. Although technically not a failure, the case when the request successfully reaches the server but the server responds with an HTTP error status code (e.g. 404, 400, 409, 500 etc.)

It is very important that one failure type is not treated as the other. Which is the correct and reliable way to do this? The `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` method seems to help with at least the second case, but the documentation is disappointingly scarce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some manual testing, the good news is that there seems to be a reliable method to separate the 2 types of errors, but the bad news is that it's not consistently the same on all platforms - at least not on Windows Phone 8. On .Net Framework 4.5 Full and on Windows Store App types of project, the following code does the trick:

```
        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // handle the second type of error (404, 400, etc.)
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            // handle the first type of error (no connectivity, etc)
        }
```

On Windows Phone 8, unfortunately, both types are handled under the `if` condition: `IsSuccessStatusCode` is set to false and no `HttpRequestException` (or any other exception, for that matter) is raised. For WP8 I'm using the portable class library implementation of `HttpClient` (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx), I asked them if this inconsistency can be fixed, hopefully it can and will soon be.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you need to have the exception handling logic  inside this (perhaps utility) method, vs. allowing clients of this method to be able to handle the two conditions. Furthermore it looks that EnsureSuccessStatusCode() also throws the same exception type `HttpRequestException`making it even harder for "clients" to distinguish. And to make things even worse, I can's seem to find a way to extract http status codes out of the exception. I guess it can be handled by composing and throwing custom exceptions, but it feels that something is missing in the framework.

Comment: Looks like the inconsistency is still present. Did you ever find a way to differentiate between no connection and a legitimate 404?

Comment: @rmorrin: If i remember well, there's a "ReasonPhrase" string property of the response object which is null (or empty) if the failure is caused by the connection to the server. It's not ideal, but i couldn't notice anything else that can be used to distinguish them - at least it seems consistent in behaviour.